# How to use groovy checkout git with verify

Tags: git, groovy

I currently have a groovy command

```
git branch: 'dev2', url: 'https://myProject/project/'
```

But it is not working because of some verify issue. The project is for public

```
 unable to access 'https://myProject/project/': Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized
```

If I run `git clone https://myProject/project/`, it has the same issue.

But if I run `env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://myProject/project/`, it works.

So I wander if groovy have the similar command which can checkout git without asking verification.

Comment: What does this have to do with groovy?

Comment: @tim_yates I'm trying to use Jenkins pipeline plugin to create jobs, I'm using groovy to fetch the repo

Comment: Can you add your groovy code to the question?

Answer (score 0):

The SSL certificate is not valid for that domain. Is it possible for you to use ssh or git instead? `git://example.com` or `git@example.com`